# Angular 6 - POSTing a file onSubmit

Tags: angular

This is what I have at the moment.

**edit-client.component.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #clientForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(clientForm)">

...

<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png">

...

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" [disabled]="!disableBtn">
```

**edit-client.component.ts**

Below is the fileChange function, uploads on a common API.

```
    fileChange(event) {

      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Authorization': `${this.authBearer}`,
        })
      };

      let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
      if(fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = this.fileList[0];
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('files', file, file.name);

        this.http.post(`${this.apiEndPoint}`, formData, httpOptions)
          .subscribe( res => {
            this.client.fileAttach = res[0].url;
            this.client.fileAttachName = res[0].name;
          })
      }
    }
```

Below is the onSubmit function, it POSTs info on firebase

```
    onSubmit({value, valid}: {value: Client, valid: boolean}) {
      console.log(this.downloadURL);
      if (!valid) {
        this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Error', 'Please fill the form correctly');
      } else {
        // Add id to client
        value.id = this.id;
        value.fileAttach = this.client.fileAttach;
        value.fileAttachName = this.client.fileAttachName;
        // update client
        this.clientService.updateClient(value);

        this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Sucess!', this.client.firstName + ' ' + this.client.lastName + ' Updated');
      }
    }
```

How can I make the file upload when I click on submit, instead of uploading when I choose the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onChange, save it to a variable in the class

so instead of:

```
let file: File = this.fileList[0];
```

You do:

```
file: File;

constructor() {}
```

....

```
this.file = this.fileList[0];

Then, on submit, you do the http logic:

submit() {
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', this.file, this.file.name);

    this.http.post(`${this.apiEndPoint}`, formData, httpOptions)
      .subscribe( res => {
        this.client.fileAttach = res[0].url;
        this.client.fileAttachName = res[0].name;
      })
}
```

Comment: Hi, your idea is good, and it sort of works if I put the rest of the submission inside the POST subscription, otherwise it will feed firebase before getting the file info. Any way around that?